# jpa deleting manytomany links

Tags: jpa, many-to-many

I have a table of events and i want to make groups of them. that is the easy easy

```
    // this cascade group still removes the join table but not the products table
@ManyToMany(targetEntity=Product.class,fetch = FetchType.EAGER, cascade = 
   {CascadeType.PERSIST, CascadeType.REFRESH,CascadeType.MERGE})
@JoinTable(name = "lcw_group_product", 
    joinColumns = { @JoinColumn(name = "group_id", referencedColumnName="id") }, 
    inverseJoinColumns = { @JoinColumn(name = "product_id", referencedColumnName="id") })
@ElementForeignKey(updateAction = ForeignKeyAction.CASCADE)
    public Set getProducts() {
        return products;
    }
```

These annotations work when i want to completely remove the group but when i want to update the group to remove some of the links, leaving the events still there, i can't find a way to do this, i am currently doing delete statements of the link table but this doesn't get reflected in the parent entity

Comment: What do you mean by doing delete statements of the link table? Are you executing native queries or are you calling em.remove(product)?

Comment: (sorry i didn't see your comment)
i am doing this to delete the child rows:
getEntityManager().remove(entity);

Comment: No answer still... Dag blammy

Answer (score 3):

Just to clarify that the ElementForeignKey is an OpenJPA annotation, not a JPA one.
Unfortunately, so far there is no orphanRemoval attribute for the ManyToMany annotation.